# Refresh previous activity if Back button is pressed

Tags: android, refresh

My app have 2 activities. The first Activity (called MainActivity) has a RecyclerView which displays some data from database, and a button which launched the second activity

**MainActivity.java**

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recView;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> data;
    Button btn1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        data = new ArrayList<String>();
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        recView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent iii = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

                // position is the index of the selected item on RecyclerView
                Bundle bnd = new Bundle();
                bnd.putString("selected_postition", ""+position);

                iii.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                iii.putExtras(bnd);

                startActivity(iii, 2112);
            }
        });

        fetchData();
    }

    public void fetchData(){
        data.clear()
        String mURL = "http://my.dev.server/api/data";

        // read table userData and display it on
        for (int x = 0; x < .....){
            data.add(....)
        }

        adapter = new MyAdapter(data);
        recView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 2112){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                int idx = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("result"));
                data.remove(idx);
                adapter = new MyAdapter(data);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**SeccondActivity.java**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FeedbackActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("");
builder.setMessage("Thank you for your feedback");
builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("result", selected_position);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
    });

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Instead of discarding the deleted rows, it will duplicatedly display existing items (tested on Android 4.4.2). How to properly refresh the RecyclerView, then?

Comment: is you api response is correct after deleting some data?

Comment: Do not refresh  in `onResume()` use `startActivityForResult()`instead .

Comment: If your having that deleted item's position number then in onActivityResult after checking the traverse from proper screen, you can delete that item from recyclerview by using that same position

Comment: @ADM. Hmm OK, I updated the code. Passing the selected index of RecyclerView from MainActivity to SecondActivity is fine.So calling `startActivityForResult` using that index should remove the item from RecyclerView, yes? In my case, nope. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             fetchData();
            Intent iii = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

            // position is the index of the selected item on RecyclerView
            Bundle bnd = new Bundle();
            bnd.putString("selected_postition", ""+position);

            startActivity(iii, 2112);
        }
    });
}
```

Try to move your `fetchData()` inside `onClick`. and on your `fetchData();`

```
  public void fetchData(){
      if(data!=null) {
        data.clear();
    }
    String mURL = "http://my.dev.server/api/data";

    // read table userData and display it on
    for (int x = 0; x < .....){
        data.add(....)
    }...some of your codes
```

Comment: Hmm I put fetchData inside onCreate, not onClick, because the RecyclerView is populated when MainActivity is loaded. onClick is for launching SecondActivity

Comment: can you screenshot the output?. I've encounter data duplication. my case its on pull to refresh